# What does it mean when var_dump reports the wrong string length?

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm trying to figure out why a variable isn't triggering a conditional that it should. var_dump reports something like this:

```
string(20) "0"
```

Why is it reporting a length of 20 when the length is clearly 1?

Comment: How does the variable get its value?

Comment: It's the return from a static function of a class. The function returns the value of the response from a call to a REST api.

Comment: What are you calling `var_dump` with?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it's doing. The response is in XML and only the content of the response (1 or 0) is getting shown. Would someone like to post this answer so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might be rendering html. i.e. `var_dump('<p class="abc">0</p>')` would output `string(20) "0"` to the naked eye

Comment: so what will be the solution ? me too facing same issue.