# Why is isset() not recognizing the variable even if it is present

Tags: php

Here is my script (part of it but it covers what i want to tell):

```
                $data = explode($this->delimeter,$buffer);
                var_dump($this->callBack);
                var_dump($columns);

                foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
                    if(isset($columns[$key]) && isset($this->callBack[$columns[$key]])) {
                        echo "called $key<br/>";
                        call_user_func(array($this,$this->callBack[$columns[$key]]),trim($val));

                    }
                }
```

And Here is its output:

```
array
  'FacilityID' => string 'setFacilityID' (length=13)
  'FacilityName' => string 'setFacilityName' (length=15)
array
  0 => string 'FacilityID' (length=13)
  1 => string 'FacilityName' (length=12)
called 1
```

My Question:
Why does `called 1` ONLY come while `called 0` doesnot come in the output? I mean `$this->callBack[$columns[$key]]` is there for both right? What am i missing.

From what i saw: `isset($columns[$key])` is `TRUE` for both while the 2nd condition of `isset($this->callBack[$columns[$key]])` is FALSE for "FacilityID" Why?

PS: From what i see all the index are defined.

**EDIT 2** My Script function in full:

```
function parseFile() {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $f=fopen($this->file,"r");
        if($f) {
            $buffer = NULL;
            $columns = array();
            $data = array();
            $firstLine = true;
            while(($buffer = fgets($f,4096)) !== false) {

                if($firstLine) {
                    $columns = explode($this->delimeter,$buffer);
                    foreach ($columns as $key=>$val) {
                        $columns[$key] = trim($val);
                    }
                    $firstLine = false;
                }
                else {
                //not first line
                    $data = explode($this->delimeter,$buffer);
                    var_dump($this->callBack);
                    var_dump($columns);
                    var_dump($data);
                    foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
                        echo $columns[$key].' ';
                        if(isset($columns[$key]) && isset($this->callBack[$columns[$key]])) {
                            echo "called $key<br/>";
                            call_user_func(array($this,$this->callBack[$columns[$key]]),trim($val));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!feof($f)) {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected error. Parsing stopped in middle");
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("File Not Found");
        }
    }
```

My Updated Output:

```
array
  'FacilityID' => string 'setFacilityID' (length=13)
  'FacilityName' => string 'setFacilityName' (length=15)
array
  0 => string 'FacilityID' (length=13)
  1 => string 'FacilityName' (length=12)
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '"Business Center"' (length=17)
FacilityID FacilityName called 1
```

Comment: Could you add `var_dump($data);` to that before the `foreach`?

Comment: The `var_dump($data)` is added after `var_dump($columns);` and the output i have updated it

Comment: @footy do you have all error reporting turned on?  Maybe an error is being generated somewhere...

Comment: Yes that was my first though and i had added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to my script.

Comment: @footy and display_errors is on too? p.s. see answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Reads past the UTF-8 bom if it is there. 
// Credit for the function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#78308
function fopen_utf8 ($filename, $mode) { 
    $file = fopen($filename, $mode); 
    $bom = fread($file, 3); 
    if ($bom != b"\xEF\xBB\xBF") {
        rewind($file, 0);
    }
    return $file; 
} 
?>
```

There should be a 24 hour lock out before Op can select "The Answer"TM. Pressing the button early is too tempting.

Comment: +1 for showing the right way. But isnt `fread($file,3)` a bit crude? I mean will it always remain 3 byes? Wont it vary from file type to file type. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Other than waiting for PHP6 which is promised to have more complete unicode support, here is a list of popular BOMs http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm

Comment: Although you should really be doing something like this aswell:      $enc = mb_detect_encoding($buffer); $data = mb_convert_encoding($buffer, "ASCII", $enc); As the BOM is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice `0 => string 'FacilityID' (length=13)` looks wrong... `FacilityID` only has length 10... not sure how you ended up with that but something to start with...  Try trimming your values in `$columns` as there must be some bad characters in there.  Or try and work out where in the rest of the execution the value is getting corrupted.

**UPDATE**

See this Q/A [What does it mean when var_dump reports the wrong string length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798532/what-does-it-mean-when-var-dump-reports-the-wrong-string-length)

Does the csv contain xml/html that could be screwing up the string length.  Also, look at using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to simplify that code a little.  You may find that alone fixes your code as it will deal with cleaning up the lines and delimiters for you.

Comment: Even i am confused. I have put up the full script. I trim it also. But still this happens. Is it goto do something with the file? Its a CSV comma separated file thats all. With 2 lines.

Comment: I have uploaded the input file in my answer and given a link to it. Also i am aware of the fgetcsv function, but was just trying out my own method instead of using that to learn. Now i know the hard way that CSV has some extra symbols in the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, works for me. Both lines are output

```
<?php
$callback = array(
  'FacilityID' => 'setFacilityID',
  'FacilityName' => 'setFacilityName'
);
$columns = array(
  0 => 'FacilityID',
  1 => 'FacilityName'
);
$data = array(
  0 => '1',
  1 => '"Business Center"'
);

var_dump($callback);
var_dump($columns);
var_dump($data);

foreach ($data as $key=>$val) {
    if(isset($columns[$key]) && isset($callback[$columns[$key]])) {
        echo "---called $key---<br/>";
        call_user_func(array($this,$callback[$columns[$key]]),trim($val));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["FacilityID"]=>
  string(13) "setFacilityID"
  ["FacilityName"]=>
  string(15) "setFacilityName"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "FacilityID"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "FacilityName"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(17) ""Business Center""
}
---called 0---<br/>PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this in /home/gerry/stack.php on line 22
PHP Warning:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /home/gerry/stack.php on line 22
---called 1---<br/>PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this in /home/gerry/stack.php on line 22
PHP Warning:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in /home/gerry/stack.php on line 22
```

So I'm guessing it's something outside the code you provided us or the data provided isn't accurate.

Comment: Yes it works for you because `0 => string 'FacilityID' (length=10)` for you where as `0 => string 'FacilityID' (length=13)` for me! What is wrong here? I read the data from a CSV file.

Comment: Not sure, but are you aware of this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: You might need to upload the input file somewhere

Comment: I have uploaded the input file in my answer and given a link to it. Also i am aware of the fgetcsv function, but was just trying out my own method instead of using that to learn. Now i know the hard way that CSV has some extra symbols in the beginning! :P

Answer (score 0):

This was a very strange error. Every one tried to answer this, but couldnt cos i found the error was not with the script but the external file i was reading from. The file is located [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/cdf3c32/n/Facilities_2.csv). If i used this somehow 3 extra characters which *was not trimmed even if `trim()` was called* was getting in to the input. If some one could shed more light on this matter it will be good. Probably this is a new question by itself.

But i solved this by just copy-pasting the contents from notepad to another file and saved it. But this is not a good method. If anyone has a better answer please post it.