# What does string() “value" mean when using var_dump

Tags: php, string

When using `var_dump` on a string I get the return of  `string(12) “55″`.  What does this mean exactly?  The value of 55 makes sense as that's what the string is defined as but what does string(12) represent?

Comment: make sure you're checking the preformatted text, and not simply the HTML output. Using a `<pre>` tag or viewing the source code works well for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the variable is a [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) of length 12. The length of 12 can be caused by:

- additional whitespace before/after `55` (use the [trim() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php))
- [HTML within the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798532/what-does-it-mean-when-var-dump-reports-the-wrong-string-length)

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte.

Comment: Example of this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the length of the string. I don't see why your script is saying 12 though..

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Bb4dfx