# wordpress: get_post() inside of a function

Tags: wordpress, type-conversion

I have this function inside of my functions.php file in my theme:
sample code......

```
function getTheAuthor($x) {
global $post;
$post = get_post($x);
$author_name = get_author_name($post->post_author);
return 'author: '.$author_name;
}
```

end sample code
so, $x is a string (let's say "375")
if I change the line to $post = get_post(375); all works ok, 
if I leave the line $post = get_post($x), I get a null object....
If I attempt to convert $x to an integer, it converts that string to zero.  --- and intval($x) = 0;
What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help

Comment: ps doing a var_dump gives me this information about $x .... string(18) "375", doing a var_dump of  intval($x) gives me this: int(0)

Comment: There's already a function for getting a post author: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I don't have the post object yet inside of this function, only the id # of the post...

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this (and, in all cases, you shouldn't need `global $post`, since you're passing a post ID to the function). The post author is stored as a post meta field with a key of `post_author`. As a result, you can use the following to return the author ID of a post:

```
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

So in your case, I'd use:

```
function getTheAuthor( $post_id ) {
    $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
    // get_author_name() is deprecated...
    $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post_author_id );
    return 'author: ' . $author_name;
}
```

Read more about `get_the_author_meta()` [in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/).

Comment: That would be helpful if I had a post object... but all I really have is a variable called $x which equals 375

Comment: That doesn't matter...then you'd use `echo getTheAuthor( $x )`. `$post_id` is just a parameter. You don't need to name your variable that.

Comment: I think the issue relates to this....
WHY is an intval of $x = 0?
var_dump of $x = .....string(18) "375"
var_dump of intval($x) = ...... int(0)

Comment: Where does `$x` come from?

Comment: What happens if you `trim( $x )` before passing it to the function?

Comment: var_dump of $x = string(18) "375"
var_dump of trim($x) = string(18) "375"
Why is it saying string(18) when there are only 3 characters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798532/what-does-it-mean-when-var-dump-reports-the-wrong-string-length

Comment: OK, I'm using visual_composer here where I can get a template tag {{ post_data:ID }} --- what I want to do is get that template tag back into a regular php variable.  apparently my var_dumping kept printing out the value of that template tag, but I want a usable value.....